# flutter rxdart Observable - how to unsubscribe

Tags: flutter, rxdart

Here is my use case:
I have a following stream set:

```
PublishSubject<RewardedVideoAdEvent> _outVideoAdController =
PublishSubject<RewardedVideoAdEvent>();
StreamSink<RewardedVideoAdEvent> get _videoAdEvents => _outVideoAdController.sink;
Observable<RewardedVideoAdEvent> get outVideoAdEvents => _outVideoAdController.stream;
```

Now, I want to listen to `outVideoAdEvents`, hence I add this to my `StatefullWidget initState` method:

```
...
    if (mounted) {
      final AdMobBloc adMob =
          BlocProvider.of<AppProvider>(context).application.adMobBloc;
      adMob.outVideoAdEvents.listen((RewardedVideoAdEvent event) {
        if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded){
           // do something meaningfull
        }
      });
...
```

So far, so good.
The issue I have got - when if I open another widget and then come back to this one, `initState` executes again and hence, I have added another listener to the same stream. Then, the next time I issue an event into `_outVideoAdController.sink`, the callback will be executed twice.

Unfortunately, unlike `initState`, `dispose` does not execute each time I load another page, so I cannot figure out how to handle the above case.

Please note, the app uses `rxdart: ^0.20.0`

Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can unsubscribe the observable by this method:

```
_outVideoAdController?.close()
```

Comment: Your suggestion will close the stream subscription and essentially will stop future event emitting. Actually, the right way to handle this is - `_videoAdSubscription = adMob.outVideoAdEvents.listen((RewardedVideoAdEvent event) {});`, then in `dispose` method - `_videoAdSubscription?.cancel();`, where `StreamSubscription<RewardedVideoAdEvent> _videoAdSubscription;` and it is local to the widget variable. Anyway - your answer directed me to the solution, so thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone else came across the same issue, these are the steps:

1. Add a private variable inside the widget from type `StreamSubscription<T>`, where `T` is your event type. In my case it is `RewardedVideoAdEvent`, hence I added `StreamSubscription<RewardedVideoAdEvent> _videoAdSubscription;`.
2. Then, when subscribing to the stream, the `listen` will return the value from this type, so just take it: `_videoAdSubscription = adMob.outVideoAdEvents.listen((RewardedVideoAdEvent event) {});`
3. Finally, when you want to unsubscribe, just call `_videoAdSubscription?.cancel();`

That's all.